# Google Calendar Api for Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I would like to create an application for Android devices that uses the Google Calendar Api. However, I got confused with the api because of the different information from all the forums and articles that I have read. My question is this, does a Google Calendar Api for Android really exists?  Because it seems like this api has little known documentations. Second, if there is, is it possible to pass data directly from an application from a device to the web?

Answer (score 6):

The official Android [Calendar Provider and API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) has quite a bit of documentation behind it, however it was only introduced in Ice Cream Sandwich (API v14) so much of the online search results may be referring to the manufacturer specific Calendar APIs they created prior to ICS or the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) (which is not Android specific or integrated into Android).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Android 4.0 Calendar API that got released in API level 14?
If you are then I've just written an article about how to get up and running with the API.
[Using the Android 4.0 Calendar API](http://www.derekbekoe.co.uk/blog/16-using-the-android-4-0-calendar-api)

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's talking about the Google Calendar API, not the Android Calendar API.